# Function parameter not found inside function

Tags: c#

This is a very bizarre problem and is really getting on my nerves.   I have a simple C# ServicesManager class I am making.  But I'm getting this problem for absolutely no apparent reason.  Anyway, here is the function in question:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This function checks if the ServicesManager contains a service of the specified type or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">The type of service to check for.</param>
    /// <returns>True if a service of the specified type is found, or false otherwise.</returns>
    public bool Contains(Type serviceType)
    {
        bool result = false;
        Type t = serviceType;


        foreach (ISE_Service s in m_ServicesList)
        {
            if (s is serviceType)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            
        }
        

        return result;
    }
```

ISE_Service is simply an interface that represents a service class.  The above function simply checks to see if a service of the specified type is already present in the ServicesManager.

The error list displays the following error, and always highlights "serviceType" in the if statement with a red squiggly line:

> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'serviceType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\MegafontProductions\SpiritEngine\SpiritEngine\Source\ApplicationLayer\ServicesManager.cs 55

This error makes no sense.  It's a parameter of this very function. As far as I can tell this problem is either caused by the is keyword or by the type Type.  As you can see, the parameter serviceType is accessed above the loop just fine.  So how is it that it suddenly can't find it inside that if statement?

Comment: How on earth is this Microsoft's fault?

Comment: Aren't you recoding ServiceLocator ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921142%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
if ((s != null) && (s.GetType() == serviceType))
```

What

```
if (s is serviceType)
```

does is ask if `s` is the type `serviceType` where `serviceType` is a specific type. Of course, it *isn't* a specific type; it's a variable of type `Type`.

`Type` is a class which represents information about a type, and it can be obtained via:

```
object.GetType(); // Returns a variable of type `Type`
```

Or:

```
typeof(MyTypeName); // Returns a variable of type `Type`
```

Yes, it's confusing because of the multiple uses of the word "Type".

Fundamentally it comes down to the difference between a compile-time type which is represented in the code by the name of a type (such as `string`, `int`, `MyType`) and a runtime type which is represented by an instance of the class called `Type`.

Comment: If you iterate thru `m_ServicesList` with `foreach`, is there any scenario where `ISE_Service s` could actually be null?

Comment: Ah I had tried that once but it was still underlining that same spot and showing me the error.  But that was because I still tried to use the is operator instead of ==.   But it works if I change it to use == like you show.  Thank you!

Comment: @Puuskis Of course it could. If `m_ServicesList` is an array or list of a reference type, any of its elements could be null.

Comment: The AddService function will make sure a value is not null before it adds it into the list.  Once one is added it will stay until the program shuts down.

Comment: @MichaelFontanini That may be so, but the code you posted doesn't define the type of `m_ServicesList` so my answer was forced to fall on the safe side. :)